# Using chronicle queue on Amazon PAS (java)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, chronicle

Can I use chronicle queue with S3 on Amazon containerized enviornment. i'm new to amazon containers, have experience with chronicle, and would love to use it on amazon.

Comment: is there any updates on this? Did you manage to find a way to read the chronicl queue file to replay the data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use chronicle on AWS, if you want to share queues between processes they need to be on the same physical machine, unless you use Chronicle Queue Enterprise which is a license product.

Comment: I dont want to use it by multiple processes, I need replay capabilities. i'm persisting market data

Comment: Can we use chronicle with S3 storage? does anybody use it with S3?

Comment: @Bit-Magic You can use it with any network storage, however you can't read it on another machine at the same time as it won't get a consistent view until it is closed (or the files are rolled)

Comment: I'm currently using StoreFileListener to upload a file to S3 once it is completed. is there a more efficient approach? streaming data from memory?

Comment: any recommendation?